# how to show objects in TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Hey everyone am trying to display an attribute of an object inside an another to make it more clear i have a class `Produit` defined like this :

```
public class Produit {
private int idproduit;
private float prixunitaire;
private String designation;
private String description;
private boolean etatp;
private Bondereduction bondereductions;
private String lienimg;
private Categorie categories;
```

}

With it getters and setters and ....

and am trying to display these data inside a TableView i use to make it like this

```
public class UpdateProdController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableColumn prixunitaire;
@FXML
private TableColumn description;
@FXML
private TableColumn designation;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Categorie,String> categorie;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Bondereduction, String> sommereduction;
@FXML
private TableColumn img;

ObservableList<Produit> prodList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private TableView<Produit> updatetable;
String xx="";
/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {



  ProduitService pss = new ProduitService();
    prodList = pss.SelectProduits();
    //String des =prodList.get(0).getCategories().getDesignation().;
    System.out.println("sqsdqsdqsd   " + prodList);


    updatetable.setItems(prodList);
    prixunitaire.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("prixunitaire"));
    description.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
    designation.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("designation"));
   sommereduction.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Bondereduction.sommereduction"));
   categorie.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Categorie.designation"));

    img.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lienimg"));
}
```

when i execute this code i get only `categorie` and `sommereduction` TableColumn empty and the problem is in these 2 lines

```
   sommereduction.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Bondereduction.sommereduction"));
   categorie.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Categorie.designation"));
```

can anyone help me how to change `PropertyValueFactory<>` to get an object and not string so it would understand that am trying to display a field inside an object. Thanks to any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to go a little further in depth with your `PropertyValueFactory<>` something like this:

```
sommereduction.setCellValueFactory(
        Produit -> {
            SimpleObjectProperty property = new SimpleObjectProperty();
            property.setValue(Produit.getValue().getBondereduction().getSommereduction()));
            return property;
        }
);
```

This should do what you need. It is basically what you did, except it took it a step further.

It creates a new `SimpleObjectProperty` and then uses the `Produit` class to grab the `Bondereduction` and it uses that value to return the `sommereduction`.

I also suggest changing the

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Categorie,String> categorie;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Bondereduction, String> sommereduction;
```

to be

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Produit,String> categorie;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Produit, String> sommereduction;
```

Since that is the class you are attempting to display.